# Number ends with a 0 or 5?

Tags: python

In Python, how would I figure out if a number ends with a 0 or 5?  And if it does not end in a 0 or a 5, set a variable to end in a 0 or a 5. 
 I think I need to use MOD or FLOOR  and some logic?
For example: 
 if I have 1301, I want 1300 
 if I have 1302, I want 1300
 if I have 1305, I want 1305
 if I have 1300, I want 1300

Comment: It is ambiguous if you want rounding or floor behavior. What should happen to `1303`? Should it be `1300` (floor) or `1305` (rounding)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to round a number to an even increment such as 5 you can do the following

```
x = 1301
increment = 5
rounded = x - (x % increment)

--> rounded = 1300
```

Answer (score 1):

To find out if a number ends in 0 or 5, use modulo `%`:

```
if mynumber % 5 == 0:
    print( "Ends in 5 or 0" )
else:
    print( "Ends in something else" )
```

To get a number rounded down to the nearest five, use the integer division operator `//` and multiply:

```
 mynumber = mynumber // 5 * 5
```

**Note** that in Python 2.x, you would just use a regular divisor `/`, or you could import `//`:

```
 from __future__ import division
```